# Harmonic map into sphere

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, proof-verification

Let $B$ be the unit ball and $S$ the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Consider the map $u: B\rightarrow S$ defined as:
\begin{equation}
u^j(x)=\frac{x_j}{|x|}\quad\forall \ j =1, 2, 3.
\end{equation}I would like to show that for each $j=1, 2, 3,$ we have
\begin{equation}
-\triangle u^j=|Du|^2u^j\quad \text{in }B\setminus\{0\}.
\end{equation}

My working is as below but I can't exactly establish the relationship; I am missing a factor of two and I don't know where I am going wrong.

Firstly, we have
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial u^j}{\partial x_i}=\frac{|x|\delta_{ij}-x_jx_i|x|^{-1}}{|x|^2}=\frac{\delta_{ij}}{|x|}-\frac{x_ix_j}{|x|^3}
\end{equation}where $\delta_{ij}=1$ if $i=j$ and zero otherwise. Consequently,
\begin{align}
|Du|^2=\sum_{j=1}^3\sum_{i=1}^{3}\left(\frac{\partial u^j}{\partial x_i}\right)^2&=\sum_{j=1}^3\sum_{i=1}^{3}\frac{|x|^2\delta_{ij}-2\delta_{ij}x_ix_j+|x|^{-2}x_j^2x_i^2}{|x|^4}\\
&=\frac{3}{|x|^2}-\frac{2}{|x|^2}+\frac{1}{|x|^2}\\
&=\frac{2}{|x|^2}.
\end{align}

So
\begin{equation}
|Du|^2u^j=\frac{2x_j}{|x|^3}.
\end{equation}

For the left hand side, however, I end up with
\begin{align}
-\sum_{i=1}^3\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left(\frac{\partial u^j}{\partial x_i}\right)&=\sum_{i=1}^3-\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left(\frac{\delta_{ij}}{|x|}\right)+\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left(\frac{x_ix_j}{|x|^3}\right)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^3\frac{\delta_{ij}x_i}{|x|^3}+\frac{|x|^3x_j-3|x|x_i^2x_j}{|x|^6}\\
&=\frac{x_j}{|x|^3}
\end{align}

Somewhere I am missing a factor of two and I can't spot it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part is correct. In the second, you did not correctly account for the derivative of $x_ix_j$ with respect to $x_i$, in the case $i=j$. Let's separate the two cases: 
$$
\begin{align}
-\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\left(\frac{\partial u^j}{\partial x_i}\right)
&=-\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\left(\frac{1}{|x|}\right)+\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\left(\frac{x_j^2}{|x|^3}\right) \\ 
&=\frac{x_j}{|x|^3}+\frac{2x_j}{|x|^3}+x_j^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\left(\frac{1}{|x|^3}\right) 
\end{align}
$$
and for $i\ne j$,
\begin{align}
-\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left(\frac{\partial u^j}{\partial x_i}\right)
& = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left(\frac{x_ix_j}{|x|^3}\right) \\ 
& =  \frac{x_j}{|x|^3} +x_ix_j \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left(\frac{1}{|x|^3}\right) 
\end{align}
Adding everything and using the identity
$$
x_j\sum_{i=1}^3 x_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left(\frac{1}{|x|^3}\right) = -\frac{3x_j}{|x|^3}
$$
we end up with $1+2+2-3=2$ copies of $x_j/|x|^3$.